# How to add "ON UPDATE SET NULL" to foreign key constraint?

Tags: php, laravel-4

How can I use the Laravel Schema Builder to add "ON UPDATE SET NULL" to my foreign key constraint?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why to set as null on update; but this is the idea:

You can delete the existent constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_symbol;
```

And create it again

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
ADD CONSTRAINT my_new_FK
FOREIGN KEY (column_in_this_table) 
REFERENCES other_table  (other_table_pk_column) 
ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

You can find more information about constraints and the alter table statement in the mysql documentation.

[Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

[ALTER TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: I want to do this using the [Laravel schema builder](http://laravel.com/docs/schema#foreign-keys).